# How to populate combobox dropdown in userform from Excel data?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

How do I populate a combobox in a userform with the values in an Excel sheet?
Say sheet name as "Reg ALL - current".
I need to populate the value from cell AI (which is a date column).

Also I need to increment the date one day from AJ to cell BF.
Example: if AI holds value (19/06/2019) then AJ should hold (20/06/2019) and so on until BF.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The ComboBox has an `AddItem` method and a  `List` property both of which can be used to assign to it. It's not at all clear what the rest of your question is talking about incrementing dates on a worksheet. Please try to improve this question.

Comment: You can also look into the `.RowSource` property.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways. If you have one set range of cells (that's what I assume reading your question) that won't change, you could just set the `RowSource` property of your combobox.

For example:

[image]

[image]

Apply to your situation:

- Cell `AI1` holds your date
- Cell `AJ1` holds formula `=AI1+1`
- Drag formula to cell `BF1` (assuming you always want to add to the value in `AI1`, the formula will keep doing this for you)
- Use `RowSource` property and fill in `=Sheet1!AI1:BF1`

Conclusion, no VBA needed at all! If I understood your question well enough that is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution
Just add a button, paste this.

```
Dim i As Long

'Clear existing items
ComboBox1.Clear

'36 (AJ) column to 58 (BF) column
For i = 36 To 58

    ComboBox1.AddItem ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value

Next i
```